# How to change the default timeout for an Azure Queue storage QueueClient.CreateIfNotExists()?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-store

I'm trying to use the v12 SDK of Azure Queues.

When I create my queue instance, the first thing I'm doing on application startup is to see if the queue exists. [Based on the typical documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet#create-a-queue):

```
// Get the connection string from app settings
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"];

// Instantiate a QueueClient which will be used to create and manipulate the queue
QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, "myqueue");

// Create the queue
queueClient.CreateIfNotExists();
```

This is great .. but .. if the code cannot access the Queue storage (e.g. bad connection string / localhost storage emulator hasn't 100% started up yet, etc) .. then it hangs for a long time .. before my Polly code kicks in for it's "retry policy".

Questions:

- Is there a way to let the client fail/quit after 5 seconds instead of me having to wait 30 or 60 seconds (like that's some default setting, deep down).
- Does the client auto-retry? If yes, this means I don't need my polly code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to let the client fail/quit after 5 seconds instead of
> me having to wait 30 or 60 seconds (like that's some default setting,
> deep down).

Please try the code below. It's a bit convoluted approach to set the request timeout in the new SDK. In the code, I am forcing the request to timeout after 10ms and instructing the SDK to not retry the request (`options.Retry.MaxRetries = 0;`)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)
        };
        var transport = new HttpClientTransport(httpClient);
        QueueClientOptions options = new QueueClientOptions()
        {
            Transport = transport,
        };
        options.Retry.MaxRetries = 0;
        var queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, "test", options);
        queueClient.CreateIfNotExists();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

> Does the client auto-retry? If yes, this means I don't need my polly
> code...

Yes it does. Here's the default retry policy:

[image]

Comment: Also, I think `options.Retry.NetworkTimeout = Timespan.FromSeconds(5)` also works, instead of making the new `HttpClient` ...

Comment: NetworkTimeout will timeout each individual network request however the operation would be retried based on the retry policy if I understand correctly.

Comment: @gauravmantriais - sincerely sorry, but I don't understand what you mean / the difference is :( Any chance you might be able to elaborate, please?

Comment: No need to apologize . Let me run some tests so that I can elaborate on my comment.

Comment: Thanks @gauravmantriais - looking forward to seeing the results :)